# c++ destructor didn't get called?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a class:

```
class Rectangle { 
     int width; 
     int height; 
 public: 
     Rectangle(int w, int h) { 
       width = w; 
       height = h; 
       cout << "Constructing " << width << " by " << height << " rectangle.\n"; 
     } 

     ~Rectangle() {  
        cout << "Destructing " << width << " by " << height << " rectangle.\n"; 
      }  
     int area() { 
          return width * height; 
     } 
};


int main() 
{ 
     Rectangle *p; 

     try { 
         p = new Rectangle(10, 8); 
     } catch (bad_alloc xa) { 
        cout << "Allocation Failure\n"; 
        return 1; 
     } 

     cout << "Area is " << p->area(); 

     delete p; 

     return 0;     
}
```

This is a quite simple C++ sample. I compiled in Linux g++ and run it.
Suddenly I found the `delete p` did not call ~Rectangle() ...
I should see string like `"Destructing " << width << " by " << height << " rectangle."`
but I did not ....

but why?
Deleting an object should call that object's destructor, shouldn't it?

Comment: Can you post the code of your destructor and the piece of code actually calling it?

Comment: The last message printed before `delete` is invoked does not end with a newline. Chances are the destructor message ends up concatenated to `Area is 80`, you might have missed it.

Comment: [It does](http://ideone.com/2fTkV) Show us the code **You** compiled and ran.

Comment: Yeah. I can confirm this code works fine. Use the GDB debugger.

Comment: YEs...Thanks , cout << "Area is " << p->area() << "\n"  ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't ended the line, so the line was not output.  Add `<< endl` to your printing.

Comment: Curious. Why isn't the buffer flushed when the program exits?

Comment: Constructing 10 by 8 rectangle. Area is 80Destructing 10 by 8 rectangle.   They are merged to one line and I missed it !!!

Comment: @sharptooth: Good question! I think that on some systems, it might be flushed even though there's no newline at the end (since some of the comments suggest 'it works' - those might be Linux-ish systems).  However, IIRC, if the last line of output does not end with a newline and the file is a text file, there is no guarantee in the standard that it will be output.  Finding chapter and verse for that could be a little tricky, though!